# Piling up flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve kind of a button-controlled slideshow, involving a `div` for a full-width picture on the top of the page, a `div` for another full-width picture on the bottom of the page and a final `div` for the central content (which includes buttons controlling the "slideshow").

So, basically, the buttons on the central div triggers picture change on both top and bottom div. There is a "neutral" picture on each of these div when no button is active ; when one is active, both top and bottom picture switch for other pictures.

I actually managed to do this, using Flexbox for `div` positionning and jQuery to show/hide pictures according to which button is active.

But my issue is I can't really animate (slide, fade, ...) my pictures ; they are placed in the background of their respective `div` ; I tried displaying all at the same time, hoping on will be displayed behind the other, but it seems that only the first is actually displaying.

My question is : is it possible to make Flexbox items piling up, so I could stack two divs, one on top of the other, allowing me to make a "discover" effect (thus I need to have a first div on the back and second div on the front that slides in) ?

Here is my code (sorry, selectors are partially in french and I didn't included the pictures) :

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i';
 body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#bloc-central {
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  align-self: center;
  order: 2;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
#bloc-central-in {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
/* ==================
   FONDS HAUT ET BAS
   ================== */

/* ----- POSITIONNEMENT DES 2 FONDS ----- */

#background-top,
#background-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
#background-top > *,
#background-bottom > * {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
#background-top {
  align-self: flex-start;
  order: 1;
}
#background-bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
  order: 2;
}
/* ----- FONDS NEUTRES ----- */

.background-neutre-top {
  background: #f00 no-repeat center 50% fixed;
}
.background-neutre-bottom {
  background: #f00 no-repeat center -50% fixed;
}
/* ----- FONDS MODE ----- */

.background-mode-top {
  background: #bbb no-repeat center 50% fixed;
}
.background-mode-bottom {
  background: #bbb no-repeat center -50% fixed;
}
/* ----- FONDS COIFFURE ----- */

.background-coiffure-top {
  background: #313131 no-repeat center 50% fixed;
}
.background-coiffure-bottom {
  background: #313131 no-repeat center -50% fixed;
}
/* ----- FONDS INSTITUT ----- */

.background-institut-top {
  background: #000 no-repeat center 50% fixed;
}
.background-institut-bottom {
  background: #000 no-repeat center -50% fixed;
}
#bloc-univers {
  align-self: center;
}
#select-univers {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  color: #c9c9c9;
}
.titre-ligne {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.titre-ligne:before,
.titre-ligne:after {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 1px;
  content: '\a0';
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
}
.titre-ligne:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.titre-ligne:after {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.btn-univers:link,
.btn-univers:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.750em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #c9c9c9;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#btn-mode:hover {
  color: #f08945;
  border: 1px solid #f08945;
}
#btn-coiffure:hover {
  color: #0fc798;
  border: 1px solid #0fc798;
}
#btn-institut:hover {
  color: #3f9cf2;
  border: 1px solid #3f9cf2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="flex-container">
  <div id="background-top">
    <div class="background-neutre-top"></div>
    <div class="background-mode-top"></div>
    <div class="background-coiffure-top"></div>
    <div class="background-institut-top"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="background-bottom">
    <div class="background-neutre-bottom"></div>
    <div class="background-mode-bottom"></div>
    <div class="background-coiffure-bottom"></div>
    <div class="background-institut-bottom"></div>
  </div>




  <div id="bloc-central">
    <div id="bloc-central-in">
      <div class="container">

        <div id="logo-viceversa" class="col-md-6">LOGO</div>

        <div id="bloc-univers" class="col-md-6">
          <div class="row text-center" id="select-univers">
            <span class="titre-ligne">CHOISISSEZ VOTRE UNIVERS</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div><a id="btn-mode" class="btn-univers" href="#">MODE</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div><a id="btn-coiffure" class="btn-univers" href="#">COIFFURE</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div><a id="btn-institut" class="btn-univers" href="#">INSTITUT</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: you don't want to use jquery?

Comment: @LGSon : Thank you for your answer. I tried displaying all of the background DIVs (as my code is currently written), but only the first is actually displaying. I aimed to manipulate these DIVs with jQuery (see my answer to blonfu below). I tried to play with z-index, display and opacity properties, mostly.

Comment: @blonfy : Thank you for your answer. In fact I want to use jQuery to "animate", but seems like I'm stuck on the positionning aspect. I tried some things with jQuery : hide and show, slideIn, CSS manipulation (display, opacity, z-index), but I never ended up with 2 "layers" placed on top of each other. I only have appear / disappear effect on one DIV with nothing behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I do the fade between the images with `z-index` and `opacity`, maybe the code is not very clean but you can take the idea:

```js
$(".btn-univers").click(function() {
  var buttonId = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
  var buttonName = buttonId[1];
  var bgTop = ".background-" + buttonName + "-top";
  var bgBottom = ".background-" + buttonName + "-bottom";
  $("#background-top > div").each(function() {
    var zIndex = $(this).css("z-index");
    if (zIndex == 2) {
      $(this).css("z-index", "1")
    }
    if (zIndex == 3) {
      $(this).css("z-index", "2")
    }
  });
  $("#background-bottom > div").each(function() {
    var zIndex = $(this).css("z-index");
    if (zIndex == 2) {
      $(this).css("z-index", "1")
    }
    if (zIndex == 3) {
      $(this).css("z-index", "2")
    }
  });
  if ($(bgTop).css("z-index") != 2) {
    $(bgTop).css({
      "z-index": "3",
      "opacity": "0"
    }).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500);
    $(bgBottom).css({
      "z-index": "3",
      "opacity": "0"
    }).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500);
  }

});
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i';
 body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#bloc-central {
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  align-self: center;
  order: 2;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
#bloc-central-in {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
/* ==================
   FONDS HAUT ET BAS
   ================== */

/* ----- POSITIONNEMENT DES 2 FONDS ----- */

#background-top,
#background-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
#background-top > *,
#background-bottom > * {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#background-top {
  align-self: flex-start;
  order: 1;
}
#background-bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
  order: 2;
}
/* ----- FONDS NEUTRES ----- */

.background-neutre-top {
  background: url(http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Rope.jpg) no-repeat center 50% fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
.background-neutre-bottom {
  background: url(http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Rope.jpg) no-repeat center -50% fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* ----- FONDS MODE ----- */

.background-mode-top {
  background: url(http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Circus.jpg) no-repeat center 50% fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
.background-mode-bottom {
  background: url(http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Circus.jpg) no-repeat center -50% fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
/* ----- FONDS COIFFURE ----- */

.background-coiffure-top {
  background: url(http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-FairyLights.jpg) no-repeat center 50% fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
.background-coiffure-bottom {
  background: url(http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-FairyLights.jpg) no-repeat center -50% fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
/* ----- FONDS INSTITUT ----- */

.background-institut-top {
  background: url(http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Bottles.jpg) no-repeat center 50% fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
.background-institut-bottom {
  background: url(http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Bottles.jpg) no-repeat center -50% fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
#bloc-univers {
  align-self: center;
}
#select-univers {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  color: #c9c9c9;
}
.titre-ligne {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.titre-ligne:before,
.titre-ligne:after {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 1px;
  content: '\a0';
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
}
.titre-ligne:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.titre-ligne:after {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.btn-univers:link,
.btn-univers:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.750em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #c9c9c9;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#btn-mode:hover {
  color: #f08945;
  border: 1px solid #f08945;
}
#btn-coiffure:hover {
  color: #0fc798;
  border: 1px solid #0fc798;
}
#btn-institut:hover {
  color: #3f9cf2;
  border: 1px solid #3f9cf2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flex-container">
  <div id="background-top">
    <div class="background-neutre-top"></div>
    <div class="background-mode-top"></div>
    <div class="background-coiffure-top"></div>
    <div class="background-institut-top"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="background-bottom">
    <div class="background-neutre-bottom"></div>
    <div class="background-mode-bottom"></div>
    <div class="background-coiffure-bottom"></div>
    <div class="background-institut-bottom"></div>
  </div>




  <div id="bloc-central">
    <div id="bloc-central-in">
      <div class="container">

        <div id="logo-viceversa" class="col-md-6">LOGO</div>

        <div id="bloc-univers" class="col-md-6">
          <div class="row text-center" id="select-univers">
            <span class="titre-ligne">CHOISISSEZ VOTRE UNIVERS</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div><a id="btn-mode" class="btn-univers" href="#">MODE</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div><a id="btn-coiffure" class="btn-univers" href="#">COIFFURE</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div><a id="btn-institut" class="btn-univers" href="#">INSTITUT</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time !
I'll check that out and give you a feedback ;)

Comment: Ok, there are some bugs, for example when you click in the same button three times but I hope this helps you